# Accessing parent object attribute from child's object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys

I have a model called Category which looks like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  belongs_to :category,:foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

I have a view which shows all the categories with some of their attributes.  I can access `category.parent_id`, but I would like to be able to do something like `category.parent_name`.
I can see myself creating a model method to fetch all categories and filling the collection with the correspondent parent name of each category, but I'm wondering if there is anyway to do this easily.

**EDIT:** I have modified the model to have it like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

The migration to create the table categories is like this:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :parent_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However when I pass a category object to a view I am not able to access its parent attributes by doing `category.parent.name` - Doing an `inspect` of that object gives me:

```
<Category id: 2, name: "Test 2", description: "Prova 2", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-17 19:28:33", updated_at: "2012-01-17 19:28:33">
```

And if I do an inspect of `category.parent` I get this:

```
#<Category id: 1, name: "Prova", description: "Test", parent_id: nil, created_at: "2012-01-17 19:28:17", updated_at: "2012-01-17 19:28:17">
```

However if I try to do `category.parent.name` I get the following error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

EDIT2: I was trying to access a parent that was nil before the object that I mentioned above.  Doing this:

```
category.parent.try(:name)
```

as suggested by **Michael Irwin** in one of the answers solved it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Self referencing associations are hard at the first time...

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

Then you could call `category.children`and `category.parent` and also access all the attributes of the asscoiated oobjects,...

Comment: davidb thanks for the answer. Why do you declare two foreign keys with the same name in the assocation has_many and belongs_to ?

Comment: I have explained my problem a little bit further using the modifications you suggested.  Let's see if I figure out what am I doing wrong..

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but `category.parent.name` should work. If a category doesn't have a parent, do something like `category.parent.try(:name)` to avoid getting a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: no idea why the no method error happens, but this helped alot. thanks