# Retrieving associated data with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have the following associations in the context of a status feed. User which has_many spots which has_many microposts. Micropost contains a field content with the post and two associated field user_id and spot_id

Contoller:

```
def home
  @feed_items = current_user.feed
end
```

In user Model:

```
def feed
  Micropost.where("user_id IN (:following_ids) OR user_id = :user_id",
                following_ids: following_ids, user_id: id)
end
```

Micropost Model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spot
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Spot Model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :microposts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :microposts
```

Spots table

```
create_table "spots", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "city"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

With this model I can easily retrieve the user name with

```
feed_item.user.name
```

Now, I would like to retrieve the name of the spot but

```
feed_item.spot
```

gives me

```
 #<Spot:0x007f3bc6c74f08>
```

not the name of the spot

```
feed_item.spot.name
```

gives me

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
feed_item.spot_id
```

gives me the correct spot_id but I am not sure how I should retrieve the spot name from this. Could anyone give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: does the Spot model have a `name` column or attribute? Would be helpful to see the other models

Comment: I have adde d the spot model and the spot tables. Yes the spot table has a name attribute.

Comment: `#<Spot:0x007f3bc6c74f08>` seems like an ActiveRecord association. If you do `feed_item.spot.inspect` what is the output?

Comment: If I do feed_item.spot.inspect the output is #<Spot id: 19, name: "XX", city: "XX", created_at: "2016-02-22 23:07:29", updated_at: "2016-02-22 23:07:29">

Comment: The answer was already given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899624/accessing-parent-object-attribute-from-childs-object-in-rails

Comment: Are you referring to `feed_item.spot.try(:name)`? Or using foreign keys?

Answer (score -1):

`user_id` foreign key is missing from the `spot table`