# Rails Understanding Active Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have issues understanding Active Record Association. I have the following

```
<%= feed_item.spot.inspect %>
```

which gives me the following output

```
#<Spot id: 18, name: "XX", city: "XX", created_at: "2016-02-22 22:30:00", updated_at: "2016-02-22 22:30:00">
```

EDIT:

I want to get the name (XX) of the spot?

```
<%= feed_item.spot.name %>
```

does not seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: The answer was already given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899624/accessing-parent-object-attribute-from-childs-object-in-rails

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because the `spot` is `nil`. If your `spot` is allowed to be `nil` you should test the value before.

```
<%= feed_item.spot.name if feed_item.spot.present? %>
```

If it isn't allowed to be `nil` add a presence validator to your `feed_item` model.

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :spot_id
end
```

With that you can be sure that `spot` is never `nil` in a fresh database.

Comment: Why do I get this: #<Spot id: 18, name: "XX", city: "XX", created_at: "2016-02-22 22:30:00", updated_at: "2016-02-22 22:30:00"> if the spot is nil? This is exactly why I am confused. Should I not get "nil" when I do spot.inspect?

Comment: Add `<%= p feed_name.spot %>` right before `<%= feed_item.spot.name %>` in your view and look what the console shows. It should return `nil`.