# When rendering an object in JSON from the controller, how do I include a field from the object's parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, controller, format

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  When returning an object via a show method, I want to include an object from the object’s parent.  I tried

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      @my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
      format.json { render :json => @my_object.to_json(:include => [:parent, :include => :address]) }
    end
  end
```

However this is producing the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `include' for #<MyObject:0x007fa1b433d788>):
```

What’s the right way to include an object from my parent?

**Edit:** here's the parent model in my Rails app

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true   #, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Using `:methods` might help. See https://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods

Comment: How would that help?  "address" is an association of the parent object, not a method.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899624/accessing-parent-object-attribute-from-childs-object-in-rails

Comment: I included my parent model in my question.  I do make the association.  Unfortunately, what is returned on the client side is my_object.parent.address_id instead of the "my_object.parent.address" object that I want.  I do have the address association set up in my model, as I put in an edit to my question.

Comment: If you can go into your rails console and get the values that you want (my_object.parent.address.street_name or whatever), confirming that your associations are correct, then I would suggest using something like jbuilder, which will help you explicitly define the structure of the JSON you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
def show

  @my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
  render :json => @my_object.to_json(:include => [:parent => {:include => :address}]) 

end
```

You have added include within the include statement,

```
@my_object.to_json(:include => [:parent, **:include** => :address])
```

so rails is searching include as one of the method or model.

You can use a array like this for including more than one relationship.

```
:include => [:parent, :address]
```